# What surface to use for a scrolling parallax interface with Famo.us

Tags: parallax, famo.us

I would like to create an interface based on 3 layers stacked that produce an horizontal scrolling parallax on user input (on swipe). Each layer got image placed randomly.

Should I use a ScrollingSurface (that is let say 300% of the screen width ) or just a simple surface a layer ? (or another more clever option)

Comment: Trying out on your own and checking in all devices is a very clever option at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used is to create all the surfaces a the same 'index' and programatically create the parallax effect based on touchSync